# Cross section side length as a function of height

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]A pond has been dug at the Indian Statistical Institute as an inverted truncated pyramid with a square base (see figure below). The depth of the pond is $6 \mathrm{~m}$. The square at the bottom has side length $2 \mathrm{~m}$ and the top square has a side length of $8 \mathrm{~m}$. Water is filled in at a rate of $\frac{19}{3}$ cubic meters per hour. At what rate is the water level rising exactly 1 hour after the water started to fill the pond ?

> I have managed to solve it but with a rather guess that crossection side changes in linear fashion with height , but in general can we show that at a distance(height) x from the square base of 2m cross section , what will be the cross section ? Given that at x=6m its a cross section side of 8m?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

For convenience extend slant heights of truncated tetrahedron to apex O shown, adding tetrahedron volume $V_0$

By similar triangles, slope s of midface slant line is

$$ s= \frac{4-1}{6}= \frac{1}{2} = \frac{x}{h}= \frac{\dot x}{\dot h}\tag1 $$

Dots denote rate differentiation with respect to time in hours.

Cross section has a square side = 2x =h.

Remaining volume after truncation of constant volume $V_0 $ since volume coefficient is known $\dfrac13$ for cones/pyramids/polyhedra etc. multiplying base area and height,

$$ V= \frac {(2x)^2 h}{3} -V_0 \tag 2 $$

From (1) and (2), plug in for h from h/x

$$ V = \frac{4}{3}x^2 . 2x-V_0 =\frac{8 x^3}{3}-V_0 \tag 3 $$

Differentiating to get ode of given volume rate:

$$\frac{dV}{dt}= 8 x^2 \frac {dx}{dt} = \frac{19}{3}  \tag 4 $$

Integrating to obtain x using boundary condition $ t=0, x=1 $

$$ x^3-1=\frac{19 \;t}{8} \tag 5 $$

Evaluating x at t=1

$$ x^3= \frac{27}{8}\to x= \frac32 =1.5\; m \tag 6$$

Since from (1) $ x=\dfrac{h}{2}$ (4) becomes
$$ x^2 \frac{dh}{dt}= \frac{19}{12} \tag 7$$

For x= 1.5 m

$$ \frac{dh}{dt}=\frac{19}{27} \approx  0.703704 \; m/hr \tag 8 $$